# Resetting form value in knockout after post

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I am currently working on resetting form to default initial value after posting.
I have try and work on it and come out with the solution as follow, but it become cumbersome and repetitive as the form field grow. As such, I am looking for a more generic solution which are able to reset the form to the initial ko.observable value set (whether it is null or not) without resetting the value of the form as follow. Hope someone be able to give a hand on this.

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.valueA = ko.observable(); // for textbox,textarea.... binding
  self.valueB = ko.observable("Hello"); // for textbox binding
  self.valueC = // json for select option binding
  self.valueD = // json for for checkbox binding
  self.valueE = 3 // selected select option binding
  .....
    
  self.PostForm =  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {},
      complete: {
         self.ValueA(null);
         self.ValueB(null);
         $('#checkbox1').val(3);
         ...
         // turn validation message off
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might consider creating a model object to back your form. resetting would be a matter of just replacing with a new instance:

```
var Model = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.valueA = ko.observable();
    self.valueB = ko.observable(); 
    self.valueC = [];
    self.valueD = [];
    self.valueE = ko.observable(3);
};

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.model = ko.observable(new Model());

  self.PostForm =  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {},
      complete: {
         self.model(new Model());
         ...
         // turn validation message off
      }
    });
}
```